# Sum data frame column if greater than 0 or less than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` that look like:

```
                   A            B           C
Date           
24/03/2014  -0.114726   -0.076779   -0.012105
25/03/2014  -0.118673   -0.078756   -0.008158
26/03/2014  -0.132919   -0.078067   0.006088
27/03/2014  -0.153581   -0.068223   0.02675
28/03/2014  -0.167744   -0.063045   0.040913
31/03/2014  -0.167399   -0.067346   -0.040568
01/04/2014  -0.166249   -0.068801   0.039418
02/04/2014  -0.160876   -0.077259   0.034045
03/04/2014  -0.156089   -0.090062   0.029258
04/04/2014  -0.161735   -0.079317   -0.034904
07/04/2014  -0.148305   -0.080767   0.021474
08/04/2014  -0.150812   -0.074792   0.023981
09/04/2014  -0.135339   -0.079736   0.008508
10/04/2014  -0.156345   -0.083574   0.029514
```

I am looking to create 2 variables that are the sum of column `C` where values are greater than 0 and where values are less than zero.

So in this example variable `aboveZero` would equal 0.259949 and the variable `belowZero` would equal -2.29261.

Comment: Can you add an ideal output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer generator expression syntax:

```
aboveZero = sum(x for x in df["C"] if x > 0)
belowZero = sum(x for x in df["C"] if x < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var1=df[df.C.lt(0)]['C'].sum()#less than 0
var2=df[df.C.gt(0)]['C'].sum()#greater than 0
```